# ReadAsStringAsync using cts.Token

Tags: c#, httpclient

Is it possible to use cts.Token when i'am reading async via httpClient?

Here is what i'm trying to do.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20000);
                var response = await client.PostAsync("http://" + MyIp + ":9090/api/SqlAction/", new StringContent(postQuery, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"), cts.Token);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {

                    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(cts.Token);
               }
```

But i am taking 
Error   CS1501  No overload for method 'ReadAsStringAsync' takes 1 arguments

Comment: `response.Content` is of type `HttpContent`, and `ReadAsStringAsync` doesn't take any parameters. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasstringasync?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_Http_HttpContent_ReadAsStringAsync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it isn't because the method [`ReadAsStringAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent.readasstringasync(v=vs.118).aspx) hasn't an overloaded method which accepts a `CancellationToken` as argument!

You could check before if a cancellation was requested:

```
if (!cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested && response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: Is there any other method which i can read string async using  cts token?

Comment: @ddd If you have a look into the documentation for the [HttpContent Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent(v=vs.118).aspx) there isn't any built-in method which accepts a ctx. I updated my answer a bit.